# Labels Voltages and Currents CircuiTikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am trying to create a circuit in latex with voltage and current labels. I know that, according to the documentation these labels are available to all path style components. However, I normally use node style components and have found no way to add those labels with them. I have cheched the documentation and this forum in extense and have not been able to find anything.

this is the result i am trying to obtain (note that here I am using path style components)

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
% Circuit style
\ctikzset{
    resistor = american,
    voltage = european,
    voltage dir = old,
}
\draw (0,0) to [vsource,v=$v_i$,i =$i_i$] ++ (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Circuit drawn with the previous code]

Here its my attempt to do it with node style components and the result

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
% Circuit style
\ctikzset{
    resistor = american,
    voltage = european,
    voltage dir = old,
}
\node[vsourceshape,rotate = -90](vsource) at (0,0){};;

\draw ([yshift = -40]vsource.west) to[short,l=$V_i$,i = $i_1$,v = $v_i$] ([yshift = 40]vsource.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Now. I know this can be done with ease with path style componentes.But I am more accostumed to use node style components and was wondering if there is a way to do it. Also, I was wondering how to do this with more complex components. For example with a transistor to show the different voltages such as base emmiter or base collector.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yshift should expect units, like [yshift=-40pt], nor am I sure whether yshift is applied before or after the mode is rotated.  I would use calc tikzlibrary (already loaded) coordinates, line`($ (vsource.west)!1.5!(vsource.north west)$)`  Some components have additional anchors (see manual).

Comment: `v`, `i` and `f` can be used only on path components, because in node components they have no way to know either the direction of the wires, its size, nor where they are supposed to go. If you don't want to use them in path style components, you have to position, build and add the labels manually using basic tikz commands.

Comment: And btw, you are using a path-style component here: the `short` component, which have size zero. I suspect that your problem is an XY one: why wouldn't you use path style components and be happy? And to add `v` and `i` between generic points, you can always use and `open` component.